# Inspect object with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

I have two models where A has_many B. If I load A including associated B as such:

```
a = A.find(:first, include: :bs)
```

`a.inspect` only shows the attributes of a:

```
 => "#<A id: 1, name: \"Test\", created_at: \"2012-07-02 21:50:32\", updated_at: \"2012-07-02 21:50:32\">"
```

How can I do `a.inspect` such that it displays all associated `a.bs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that by default. It might create too many problems and side effects with inspecting objects. However you could extend `inspect` yourself with something like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def inspect
    [super, bs.inspect].join("\n")
  end
end
```

Note though that that's not very clever, since it will force the loading of `bs` every time you inspect an `A` instance. So maybe you want to be smarter and do something like this:

```
def inspect
  [super, bs.loaded? ? bs.inspect : nil].compact.join("\n")
end
```

This will only inspect `bs` if it's already preloaded (with `:include` for example).

Or maybe you want to create a `super_inspect` instead that does everything automatically. You could extend `ActiveRecord::Base` with something like:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def deep_inspect
    ([inspect] + self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |a|
      self.send(a.name).inspect
    }).compact.join("\n  ")
  end
end
```

This will automatically look up all the associations with [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations), and if the association is loaded it will call `inspect` on that.

Now you can modify the above code however you want to create your own customized inspect, or just extend the current inspect if you like. Anything is possible with a little bit of code.

Here is an example of an updated version that is a bit smarter:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def deep_inspect
    ([inspect] + self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |a|
      out = ""
      assoc = self.send(a.name)
      # Check for collection
      if assoc.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)
        # Include name of collection in output
        out += "\n#{assoc.name.pluralize}:\n"
        out += self.send(a.name).to_a.inspect
      else
        out += self.send(a.name).inspect
      end
      out
    }).compact.join("\n  ")
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting this exception: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'loaded?' for nil:NilClass)`

Comment: Are you using the last suggestion? Try and replace `if self.send(a.name).loaded?` with `if self.send(a.name).try(:loaded?)`. Does that help?

Comment: Actually you can remove the whole `if ..` also if you wish. It will then simply force-load all associations. `loaded?` is not always present unless the model has an association I think.

Comment: I did remove `if ..`and got   `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
  #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
  #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` No idea what this means.

Comment: It means the model you ran `deep_inspect` on has several associations. For example `has_many`. Each of those is a `CollectionProxy`. In your case it looks like the associations were empty. If the collections had data in them you should see an array of objects inside the CollectionProxy. This is the same result you would get for example if you had `Post` and `Comments` and you would do `Post.first.comments`. You also get a `CollectionProxy` back, because Post `has_many: comments`.

Comment: See the updated post. I made a version that unrolls the CollectionProxy.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same line as the answer from @Casper, here is a helper method that marshals all associations down the dependency chain:

```
# app/models/application_record.rb
#
#   placing the helper in the ApplicationRecord superclass
#   allows all application models to inherit the helper


class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.marshal

    # collect the names of the objects associations
    single_associations = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one ).map {|x| x.name}
    plural_associations = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map {|x| x.name}

    # serialize the object as a JSON-compatible hash
    self.as_json.merge(

      # merge in a hash containing each `has_one` association via recursive marshalling
      #   the resulting set of associated objects are merged into
      #   the original object's serialized hash, each keyed by the name of the association
        single_associations.reduce({}) { |memo, assoc| memo.merge({ assoc => self.send(assoc).marshal }) }.as_json
    ).merge(

      # merge in the `has_many` associations
      #   the resulting set of associated collections must then be processed
      #   via mapping each collection into an array of singular serialized objects
        plural_associations.reduce({}) { |memo, assoc| memo.merge({ assoc => self.send(assoc).map {|item| item.marshal } }) }.as_json
    )
  end
end
```

You would then be able to call this helper method by calling:

```
Marshal.serialize a
```

This is not quite the same as an inspection, since it is actually serializing the object into a hash structure, but it will give you similar information.

---

Note that the possible associations are separated are separated into two groups: singular associations (which reference a single target object), and plural associations (which are [ActiveRecord CollectionProxy](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) objects, i.e. they are Enumerable). Because we are serializing associated objects as hashes, each `has_many` association must be parsed as a collection of individually serialized objects (e.g. we map each association within the collection as its serialized form).

The `belongs_to` association should be ignored, as mapping associations in both directions would immediately create a circular dependency graph. If you wish to marshal along the "chain of belonging" instead, you could do something like

```
def self.trace
    parent_associations = obj.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map {|x| x.name}

    obj.as_json.merge single_associations.reduce({}) { |memo, assoc| memo.merge({ assoc => obj.send(assoc).trace }) }.as_json
end
```

---