# How to convert an active record with associations to a nested hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

SO...

I am writing some code that will query an active record with associations and return the data in a format similar to...

```
[{
    foo: {
        id: ...,
        foo_property: ... 
    },
    bar: {
        id: ...,
        bar_property: ...
    }
}, ...]
```

...the top level active record and its associations all have timestamps and other fields I would like to exclude. I am aware of `attributes` and `as_json` but both of these do not follow relationships (instead replacing foo and bar with foo_id and bar_id). I am also aware of `AssociationReflection` and its ability to dynamically find associations that can with some complexity perform what I would like, but ideally...

I want a simple, elegant way to query my data with this transformation and property filtering, i.e.

```
Whatever.joins(:foos, :bars)
        .eager_load(:foos, :bars)
        .? # convert results to an array of hashes with association data (under appropriately named hash key)
        .? # filter top level entries and association data to not have timestamps, etc. (select?)
```

...thanks!

Comment: hmmm could you show us the model ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) which support associations:

```
class WhateverSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :other_attribute, :third_attribute

  has_many :foos
  has_many :bars
end
```

This allows you to specify which attributes you want in the final JSON output (through `attributes`) and let's you integrate associations (they will use `FooSerializer` and `BarSerializer` respectively).

In the corresponding controller you can just use

```
render json: whatever
```

and the object will be wrapped automatically by the serializer. Or if you have an array of `Whatever` objects you can do the following:

```
render json: Whatever.all, each_serializer: WhateverSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same behavior using a syntax like below:

Suppose a nested association like :baz has many :bars and :bar has many :foos

```
render json: Foo.includes(bar: :baz),
include: {bar: {include: {baz: {only: [:attr_a]}},
only: [:attr_b]}}, only: [:attr_1, :attr_2, :attr_3]
```

However I also recommend using [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). This syntax is not clear when you have a lot of associations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [deep_pluck](https://github.com/khiav223577/deep_pluck)

```
Whatever.deep_pluck(
  foo: [:id, :foo_property, ...],
  bar: [:id, :bar_property, ...],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers to this question give concise solutions for serializing known associations, what follows is a comprehensive tool that serializes the entire association-based dependency graph for any object, without the need to specifically enumerate every desired association:

*[this is a repost of an answer I gave for "[Inspect object with associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318353/inspect-object-with-associations/59873898#59873898)"]*

```
# app/models/application_record.rb
#
#   placing the helper in the ApplicationRecord superclass
#   allows all application models to inherit the helper


class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.marshal

    # collect the names of the objects associations
    single_associations = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_one ).map {|x| x.name}
    plural_associations = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map {|x| x.name}

    # serialize the object as a JSON-compatible hash
    self.as_json.merge(

      # merge in a hash containing each `has_one` association via recursive marshalling
      #   the resulting set of associated objects are merged into
      #   the original object's serialized hash, each keyed by the name of the association
        single_associations.reduce({}) { |memo, assoc| memo.merge({ assoc => self.send(assoc).marshal }) }.as_json
    ).merge(

      # merge in the `has_many` associations
      #   the resulting set of associated collections must then be processed
      #   via mapping each collection into an array of singular serialized objects
        plural_associations.reduce({}) { |memo, assoc| memo.merge({ assoc => self.send(assoc).map {|item| item.marshal } }) }.as_json
    )
  end
end
```

You would then be able to call this helper method by calling:

```
Marshal.serialize whatever
```

This is not quite the same as an inspection, since it is actually serializing the object into a hash structure, but it will give you similar information.

---

Note that the possible associations are separated are separated into two groups: singular associations (which reference a single target object), and plural associations (which are [ActiveRecord CollectionProxy](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) objects, i.e. they are Enumerable). Because we are serializing associated objects as hashes, each `has_many` association must be parsed as a collection of individually serialized objects (e.g. we map each association within the collection as its serialized form).

The `belongs_to` association should be ignored, as mapping associations in both directions would immediately create a circular dependency graph. If you wish to marshal along the "chain of belonging" instead, you could do something like

```
def self.trace
    parent_associations = obj.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map {|x| x.name}

    obj.as_json.merge single_associations.reduce({}) { |memo, assoc| memo.merge({ assoc => obj.send(assoc).trace }) }.as_json
end
```

---